# How to get rid of local history files in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed local history extension for my VSCode Editor. After some time I uninstalled the extension but all history files were still in place and displayed as untracked. It was not possible to get rid of them with `git clean command`, so I deleted `.history` folder created by the extension in my project. The files were deleted but they are still displayed on git status command as untracked and are marked as deleted. How can I completely get rid of all that stuff?

Comment: if they are marked as deleted it means you once have commited them, forgot to put `.history` in the `.gitignore` file

Comment: Maybe, but the question was not why they are displayed but how can I get rid of them. If I put .history folder to my .gitignore they are gone. But right after deleting .history folder they start displaying as deleted again. All that 100 items list.

Comment: what does `git status` on the terminal show you, that is leading, if VSC shows something different then VSC is in error